# Output of bash script to table

Tags: arrays, bash

This is not a text formatting question :-)

I have a script that queries remote systems and lists users on them.  If I did this serially, by just iterating through my list of hosts, this would work fine, but would take a long time.  When I do this in parallel, via subshells, the output gets a little jumbled up.  I'm thinking if the results could get stored in a table, and then the table was dumped out, maybe that would work better.  Or maybe I could create an array for each host and dump all the arrays?

I know the first answer is, "Don't do this in bash, you dummy!"  But I'm not a programmer, and while I keep intending to learn some perl or python or something, bash is the tool I have to work with today.

Comment: bash doesn't have tables. it has strings. imposing formatting/layout on those strings is up to you.

Comment: Write the output of each command to a separate file, then output the contents of the files in the desired order. I can't recommend anything more specific without some example code.

Comment: Iterate through your list of hosts, output to a separate file for each host, but do it in the background (with `&`). After the loop, `wait`. Then collect the results.

Comment: Use the `-k` option to `parallel`.